# QML ScrollBar/ListView sensitivity for mouse wheel. How to adjust

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt5.9

There is QML control ScrollBar , and mouse wheel scrolls the list fast, I need to perform this slower. Which properties can be used for that?

Qt 5.9

this is from an examples (rssnews sample project from Qt kit):

```
...
ListView {
    id: categories
    property int itemWidth: 190


    width: isPortrait ? parent.width : itemWidth
    height: isPortrait ? itemWidth : parent.height
    orientation: isPortrait ? ListView.Horizontal : ListView.Vertical
    anchors.top: parent.top
    model: rssFeeds
    delegate: CategoryDelegate { itemSize: categories.itemWidth }
    spacing: 3
}

ScrollBar {
    id: listScrollBar

    orientation: isPortrait ? Qt.Horizontal : Qt.Vertical
    height: isPortrait ? 8 : categories.height;
    width: isPortrait ? categories.width : 8
    scrollArea: categories;

    anchors.right: categories.right
}
...
```

I see this for [ScrollView](http://master.qt.io/ministro/android/qt5/objects/5.211-x86/qml/QtQuick/Controls/ScrollView.qml):

```
/*! \internal */
property alias __wheelAreaScrollSpeed: wheelArea.scrollSpeed
```

But can't find scrollSpeed property for my case...

Comment: Please add some code, If you have no clue what to try, at least some example code on which we can try it.

Comment: Also add information about the qt version you use. There are more specific tags like qt5.6, qt5.7 e.t.c.

Comment: Are you planning on using that *custom example implentation of a ScrollBar* instead of the one from `QtQuick.Controls 2.x`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the `ScrollBar` is what makes the things go wild. It is the `Flickable` that is the base class of the `ListView`.

There you have the property: `maximumFlickVelocity` which is in *pixel / second*.

Try to set this to an appropriate value.

> This will also affect the *flicking behavior!*

If it is the `ScrollBar` you might try the property: `stepSize` - set it to something smaller than `0.1`. I don't have Qt5.9 so I can't try it. I don't belive this is the reason though.

In the worst case, layer a `MouseArea` ontop of the whole thing, that does not accept any buttons, but handles `onWheel`:

```
MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    acceptedButtons: Qt.NoButton
    //onWheel: manage the scrolling yourself, here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping a MouseArea (like derM mentioned) on top of the ListView was the solution for me. Now the ListView reacts on the mouse wheel.

```
MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    ListView {
        id: lv
        anchors.fill: parent
        delegate: ...
        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
            parent: lv.parent
            anchors.top: lv.top
            anchors.left: lv.right
            anchors.bottom: lv.bottom
        }
    }
}
```